# How do I return a sys_refcursor from oracle SP in java?

Tags: stored-procedures, jdbc, oracle-cursor

I have a stored procedure (SP) in oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE "SP_SEL_LOGIN_INFO" (
p_username IN varchar2,
p_ResultSet OUT sys_refcursor
) AS

begin

OPEN p_ResultSet FOR
SELECT * FROM user_accounts
WHERE p_username = username;

end;
```

In my java class I have the following lines of code to call the SP:

```
currentCon = connectionpackage.ConnectionManager.getConnection(dbSource);
CallableStatement stmt = currentCon.prepareCall("{call SP_SEL_LOGIN_INFO(?, ?)}");
stmt.setString(1, username); 
stmt.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR); //REF CURSOR
stmt.execute();
rs = stmt.getCursor(2);
```

That is what I have found online to call a SP and return a cursor.  When I try to compile I get the following two errors:

`error: cannot find symbol stmt.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);` AND `error: cannot find symbol rs = stmt.getCursor(2);` Where it says it cannot find OracleTypes and getCursor.

I tried importing `import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;` or `import oracle.jdbc.*;` and got the errors `error: package oracle.jdbc does not exist import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;` and `error: package oracle.jdbc does not exist import oracle.jdbc.*;` respectively.

I also have the ojdbc14.jar file in the proper folder and can connect using a query string.  It is just when trying to use the SP that it is giving me trouble.

The SP is one we use on our current CF website, so I would like to just reuse it as is.  Could someone please shed some light on why this may not be working?  Or if there is an alternative bit of code to use to return a cursor from an Oracle SP?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this, it might solve the issue.

Replace this

```
rs = stmt.getCursor(2);
```

with

```
 rs = ((OracleCallableStatement)stmt).getCursor(2);
```

Besides, for calling procedure, use the below statement.

```
CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("BEGIN SP_SEL_LOGIN_INFO(?, ?); END;");
```

Comment: Thanks.  I found that I was missing a jar file, but once I added it, I still used the cast to the OracleCallableStatement.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try like this:

```
rs = (ResultSet) stmt.getObject(2);
while (rs.next()) {
     String field1 = rs.getString(1);
     System.out.println(field1);
}
```

it's running properly on my side

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone please shed some light on why this may not be working?
>   Or if there is an alternative bit of code to use to return a cursor
>   from an Oracle SP?

If you would want to return only `resultsets`(records) then why not use a function which returns `sys_refcursor` than a stored procedure? Of course it doesn't make any difference 
if you use a `procedure` or `function` in terms of performance, as `function` would be a best practice as your `procedure` is not doing any thing other than `select` statement.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
public LoanResponse getActiveLoan(LoanOverview loanDetails) {
    LoanResponse response = new LoanResponse();
    ErrorResponse error = null;
    try {
        SimpleJdbcCall procedure = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbc).withProcedureName("GET_ALL_LOAN_DETAILS_BY_USER")
                .returningResultSet("P_ASSET_RESULT", new LOAN_OVERVIEW_ROWMAPPER()));
        MapSqlParameterSource input = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("P_UUID", loanDetails.getUuid());
        Map<String, Object> result = procedure.execute(input);
        List<LoanOverview> loanDtls = (List) result.get("P_ASSET_RESULTS");
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(loanDtls) ) {
            response.setLoanOverview(loanDtls);
            error = SUCCESS_ERROR;
        } else {
            error = NODATA_ERROR;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        error = EXCEPTION_ERROR;
    }
    response.setError(error);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.