# Calling Stored Procedure in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: java, sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have written a procedure with a cursor in it in Oracle 11g so that I can use it in Java code. Can anybody tell me how I can use this procedure and call it from Java code?

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE show_students
(
students_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)AS
BEGIN
OPEN students_cursor FOR
SELECT * from students;
END show_students;
```

Comment: Any efforts appreciated!

Comment: http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-by-jdbc-java-class/169

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
CallableStatement stmt = connection.prepareCall("BEGIN SHOW_STUDENTS(?); END;");
stmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR); //REF CURSOR
stmt.execute();
rs = ((OracleCallableStatement)stmt).getCursor(1);
```

I suggest using function in this case instead of procedure.

Notice that I suppose you have the connection to DB as "connection"

Source:
[How do I return a sys_refcursor from oracle SP in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197674/how-do-i-return-a-sys-refcursor-from-oracle-sp-in-java)